# tkinter, Image does not show up unless some function added

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written a code for a basic game but the image and shape don't show up unless I add something like item.pack() or win.mainloop() [which doesn't really make sense] but then the lines below it don't run.

When I don't have anything, the buttons show up but the image doesn't show up.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random
from tkinter import messagebox

win = tk.Tk()

my_label = tk.Label(win, text="Color of the Baloon Game")
my_label.pack()

my_canvas = tk.Canvas(win, width=400, height=600)
my_canvas.pack()

background_image=tk.PhotoImage(file = "CS_Game_menu.png")
background_label = tk.Label(my_canvas, image=background_image)
background_label.photo = background_image
background_label.grid(row = 0, rowspan = 10, column = 0, columnspan = 10)


def drawCircle():
    color = "green"
    x1 = 265
    y1 = 80
    diameter = 90
    my_canvas.destroy()
    circle_button.destroy()
    quit_button.destroy()
    my_label.destroy()
    my_label1 = tk.Label(win, text="What is the Color of the Baloon?", font="Purisa")
    my_label1.pack()
    my_canvas1 = tk.Canvas(win, width=400, height=600)
    my_canvas1.pack()
    image1 = r"CS_Game_baloon.png"
    photo1 = tk.PhotoImage(file=image1)
    item = my_canvas1.create_image(200, 350, image=photo1)
    shape = my_canvas1.create_oval(x1, y1, x1 + diameter, y1 + diameter+20, fill=color)
    item.pack()
    game1_button = tk.Button(my_canvas1, text = "Green")
    game1_button.grid(row= 8, column = 3)
    game1_button["command"] = lambda: messagebox.showinfo("Congratulations!", "Correct Answer!")
    game2_button = tk.Button(my_canvas1, text = "Blue")
    game2_button.grid(row= 8, column = 5)
    game2_button["command"] = lambda: messagebox.showinfo("Sorry!", "Incorrect Answer!")
    game3_button = tk.Button(my_canvas1, text = "Red")
    game3_button.grid(row= 8, column = 7)
    game3_button["command"] = lambda: messagebox.showinfo("Sorry", "Incorrect Answer!")


circle_button = tk.Button(win, text="New Game")
circle_button.pack()
circle_button["command"] = drawCircle

quit_button = tk.Button(win, text="Quit")
quit_button.pack()
quit_button['command'] = win.destroy
```

Comment: Just curious, why `win.mainloop()` doesn't make any sense to you?

Comment: No, I mean it does make sense, but having it in the middle of the code doesn't make sense. I am sorry the phrasing of the description was bad. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using both the `create_...` methods and `grid` methods on your `canvas` object. It won't behave as you expected.

To achieve what you want, you can create a `Frame`, put your buttons in it, and then use `create_window` method on your canvas:

```
def drawCircle():
    ...
    shape = my_canvas1.create_oval(x1, y1, x1 + diameter, y1 + diameter+20, fill=color)
    frame = tk.Frame(my_canvas1)
    game1_button = tk.Button(frame, text = "Green")
    game1_button.grid(row= 8, column = 3)
    game1_button["command"] = lambda: messagebox.showinfo("Congratulations!", "Correct Answer!")
    game2_button = tk.Button(frame, text = "Blue")
    game2_button.grid(row= 8, column = 5)
    game2_button["command"] = lambda: messagebox.showinfo("Sorry!", "Incorrect Answer!")
    game3_button = tk.Button(frame, text = "Red")
    game3_button.grid(row= 8, column = 7)
    game3_button["command"] = lambda: messagebox.showinfo("Sorry", "Incorrect Answer!")
    my_canvas1.create_window(200,500,window=frame)
```

And of course, add `win.mainloop()` to the bottom of your program if you haven't already.